# How to add an image in the widget zone?

Tags: images, widgets

I want to add an image to the sidebar, where widgets are displayed. How can I do it?

Comment: Hey, simply go to your sidebar - add a text widget, inside it type the following <img src="http://example.com/picture.jpg" />

Comment: @mireilleraad - Thank you. Good option. I've already installed an image plugin and added it like a widget.